# React Native, Redux and Router Flux set state and redirect

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I'm new to React Native and have implemented a 'bodge' to get my app working but I wanted to know the correct way to implement the following...

The user has the option to log out on every page which currently calls a LOGOUT action which tells the reducers to revert back to initial states. It also sets the navigation reducer that I made to go to the 'login' screen. Once componentWillUpdate fires it sees this and then calls Actions.login(). This all works but is definitely not 'clean'.

Any advice on the correct implementation of this set state and redirect flow that I need?

I'm using the latest version of all of the libraries involved.

Comment: Your approach seems fine to me at first glance. what are your concerns with it that's making you think it's not "clean" ? can you share some code examples?

Comment: My approach means that the render is still firing after componentWillUpdate which isn't needed in my case. I'm looking at an alternate method where I build an IsLoggedIn component 'container' which only renders it's children when the user is actually logged in. I'll put together an example at some point soon but I've got to hit a deadline on this by close of business today.

Comment: You could use a HOC container that contains your application and passes an isLoggedIn prop down to every component that needs it and those components can handle the rendering based on that

Comment: I ditched router-flux in the end, it didn't seem 'finished' - I was getting errors caused by code that I had no control over. Using react-navigation now with a similar method and it works nicely

Comment: ah gotcha. I prefer react-navigation as well. been using it in my project for the past 6 months. It's a bit opinionated and verbose but other than that I've enjoyed working with it